# Need to select "Male" from the dropdown in gmail account creation page using selenium webdriver (I want to use SelectbyIndex method)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried below two codes. Both didn't select the "Male" option. Could anyone please let me know where I'm doing a mistake.

It's very difficult to post the code in this site. So many conditions

```
My code:
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    public class webelements2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
            WebElement google = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div"));
            google.click();
            Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div")));
            dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
            }
    }



Even I used sendkeys method. But it didn't work for me

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class webelements2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
        WebElement google = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div"));
        google.sendKeys("Male");
        google.click();
    }
```

Please suggest me how to overcome this problem

Comment: Just a Suggestion dear,Whenever Possible try to use `id` instead of `xpath` first if it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this and let me know if it works for you:

> For Female

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":e")).click();
```

> For Male

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":f")).click();
```

> For Other

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":g")).click();
```

> For Rather not say

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":h")).click();
```

And if you need for sign-up gmail, I tried Once:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys("Name");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys("Last name");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']")).sendKeys("Email id");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("Password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']")).sendKeys("Password Again");
//Input the month
List<WebElement> month_dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div"));
//iterate the list and get the expected month
Thread.sleep(3000);
for (WebElement month_ele:month_dropdown){
String expected_month = month_ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
// Break the loop if match found

Thread.sleep(3000);
if(expected_month.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){
    month_ele.click();
    break;
}

driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":3")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthDay']")).sendKeys("14");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthYear']")).sendKeys("1988");

driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":e")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']")).sendKeys("4694222863");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("recovery email id");
driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
```

Comment: this is working but I want to use "Select by index" method & dropdown options. Then I'm getting an issue (Element should have been "select" but was "div")                                                                                    Code:                                                                                                Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);

Comment: @BruceWayne : You cannot use select for this drop down. There is no select written under the HTML DOM for this drop-down. In fact it is written in `div`. So you can use the above thing only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select()` with `<select>`, `<option>` elements only. In this current case you can simply `click()` on drop-down and then `click()` to choose required option:

```
WebElement google = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div"));
        google.click();
WebElement option = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Male']"));
        option.click();
```

You might also need to wait until `option` to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement option = wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Male']")));
option.click();
```

Comment: Thanks Anaderson.

Comment: this is working but I want to use "Select by index" method & dropdown options. Then I'm getting an issue (Element should have been "select" but was "div")                                                                                    Code:                                                                                                Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Gender']/div")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);

Comment: As I said you can use `Select()` with `<select>` element only, but not with `<div>`